# When does c-ares use multiple sockets in parallel in a single channel?

Tags: c-ares

I'm trying to reproduce a crash happening on a user's machine. My code assumed that there could only be a single socket fd used by c-ares, but apparently that is not always true.

I'm working on a fix, but for that I'd like to be able to reproduce the crash (i.e. get c-ares to use multiple sockets) so that I am certain that I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the libc-ares code, I came to conclude that sockets are not used in parallel.

However, in case there is some error in getting a response initially (like if the UDP response was truncated, see [`TC` bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#DNS_message_format)), it will create another socket and use that.

That makes sense, of course. Users of c-ares should not make other assumptions though, like we did.